# how can i increase/decrease size of window on click event?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a simple swing app in which I have a main window with three buttons. When I click on the first button it opens new window of (200,200) dimension. When I click on the second button, the newly opened window's height should get increased and when I click on third button height should get decreased. Can you help me with code....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you could do the following on the newly opened windows which you want to resize:

```
JFrame fr=getNewlyOpenendWindowReference(); // get a reference to the JFrame
fr.setSize(fr.getSize().getWidth() + 10,fr.getSize().getHeight() + 10);
fr.repaint();
```

this should increase the size of the JFrame length and widthwise by 10 pixels per call.

Comment: Or use `setBounds` if you want the growth to not always be on the right and bottom of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Controller class to handle the action events.**

Define a `FramePanel extends JPanel` and add your buttons to it.  Set up constants in the class with action event values and set them on your buttons.  Then, you can instantiate this `FrameController` and add it as the listener to those buttons using `JButton.addActionListener()`.  Or, you can do this in the constructor of the `FrameController` class.

```
public class FrameController implements ActionListener {
  private JFrame openedFrame;

  public static final int MINIMUM_HEIGHT = 200;

  public FrameController(FramePanel panel) {
    this.panel.getOpenFrameButton().addActionListener(this);
    this.panel.getIncreaseHeightButton().addActionListener(this);
    this.panel.getDecreaseHeightButton().addActionListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if (action.equals(FramePanel.ACTION_OPEN_FRAME)) {
      this.openedFrame = new JFrame();
      // set it up how you want it
    } else if (action.equals(FramePanel.ACTION_INCREASE_HEIGHT)) {
      this.openedFrame.setSize(this.openedFrame.getWidth(), this.openedFrame.getHeight() + 10);
    } else if (action.equals(FramePanel.ACTION_INCREASE_HEIGHT)) {
      int newHeight = this.openedFrame.getHeight() - 10;
      if (newHeight < FrameController.MINIMUM_HEIGHT)
        newHeight = FrameController.MINIMUM_HEIGHT;
      this.openedFrame.setSize(this.openedFrame.getWidth(), newHeight);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi it sounds good but i m getting error."Set up constants in the class with action event values and set them on your buttons".i m not getting this part.plz tell me indetail.

Comment: Declare `public static final String ACTION_OPEN_FRAME = "OpenFrame";` in the FramePanel class.  Then, on the button, call `this.openFrameButton.setActionCommand(FramePanel.ACTION_OPEN_FRAME);`  This will ensure that the command is sent to the listener when the button is pressed so the listener knows *which* button was pressed.