# I'm making a game in Java and whenever I try to bring up my in game menu the program minimizes?

Tags: swing, runtime, java

The menu is displayed on game startup and works fine, but once in game you can hit escape to bring up the menu again and this will cause the program to minimize.  After I unminimize the game I can hit escape again and the menu screen will appear as intended.  The return button also works as intended.  What is going on here?

**EDIT**
Here is my SSCCE:
You will just need to add the imports and unimplemented methods for BullsEyePanel.  I hope this helps!

```
public class Board {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int B_WIDTH = (int) dim.getWidth();
        int B_HEIGHT = (int) dim.getHeight();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Children of The Ape");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);

        // Get graphics configuration...
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        // Change to full screen
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(f);
        if (gd.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
            gd.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT, 32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN));
        }

        MenuPanel menu = new MenuPanel(f);
        f.getContentPane().add(menu);
        f.validate();
    }
}

class BullsEyePanel extends JPanel implements MouseInputListener, ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;

    public BullsEyePanel(JFrame f) {
        frame = f;
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        repaint();
    }

    private void openMenu() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MenuPanel(this));
        setVisible(false);
    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getKeyCode() == 27) {
                openMenu();
            }
        }
    }
}

class MenuPanel extends JPanel {

    JButton btnExit;
    JButton btnNewGame;
    JFrame f;
    BullsEyePanel panel;

    MenuPanel(JFrame frame) { //this menu constructor is only called on program startup
        f = frame;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFocusable(true);

        btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnNewGame.addActionListener(new newGameListener());
        btnExit.addActionListener(new exitListener());
        add(btnNewGame);
        add(btnExit);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    MenuPanel(BullsEyePanel bullsEyePanel) { //this menu constructor is called when ESC is typed
        f = bullsEyePanel.frame;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFocusable(true);

        btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnNewGame.addActionListener(new newGameListener());
        btnExit.addActionListener(new exitListener());
        add(btnNewGame);
        add(btnExit);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class exitListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public class newGameListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setVisible(false);
            f.getContentPane().add(new BullsEyePanel(f), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what is wrong based on this fragment of code? Consider creating and posting a minimally compilable runnable example, an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: We don't have enough information to help. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the SSCCE.

Comment: +1 for sscce, _sans_ `implements MouseInputListener, ActionListener`.

Comment: If we have to add code it is still NOT an SSCCE.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of variant constructors, let the menu panel undertake its removal and restoration, as suggested below. See also this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059278/change-panel-size-on-button-click/7061696#7061696).

[image]
[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Board().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Children of The Board");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        MenuPanel menu = new MenuPanel(f);
        f.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MenuPanel extends JPanel {

    private JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    private JButton btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
    private BullsEyePanel gamePanel;
    private JFrame parent;

    MenuPanel(JFrame parent) {
        this.gamePanel = new BullsEyePanel(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        btnNewGame.addActionListener(new newGameListener());
        btnExit.addActionListener(new exitListener());
        this.add(btnNewGame);
        this.add(btnExit);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void restore() {
        parent.remove(gamePanel);
        parent.add(this, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        parent.pack();
        parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class exitListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private class newGameListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            parent.remove(MenuPanel.this);
            parent.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            parent.pack();
            parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gamePanel.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}

class BullsEyePanel extends JPanel {

    private MenuPanel menuPanel;

    public BullsEyePanel(MenuPanel menu) {
        this.menuPanel = menu;
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240)); // placeholder
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent code) {
            if (code.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                menuPanel.restore();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I still have a problem though...  The program works as intended when I use your setPreferredSize() but when I try to implement my fullscreen mode I go back to having the same problems (and some different ones).  So what's wrong with fullscreen?

Comment: Sorry, I have almost no experience with full screen mode, but I'd guess you'd need `setUndecorated()` before `setVisible()`, as well as `revalidate()` after `remove()`, instead of `pack()`.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it did fix my new problems, but the original problem remains.  So I did some more google searches and tried everything I could think of and now I ended up with this:  I just added this.requestFocus() and repaint() and the end of the restore() method. The request focus stops the game from minimizing, unfortunately the game panel would not disappear and the menu panel would be drawn behind it (or something like that), the buttons could be accessed by hitting tab.  The repaint() brings it to the foreground and now it acts as sort of a menu overlay. it works :\

Comment: I don't see the minimizing on Mac OS X. Does your platform treat the `VK_ESCAPE` key specially?

Comment: I am so confused right now...  Changing the key to something different will cause the program to apparently take no action when you type the specified key.  But if you alt-tab and then return you see it actually has restored().  If you type ESCAPE after typing the special key then the program minimizes, I can't find any mention of escape being special (I'm using windows). So it seems I have an issue with the screen updating but as far as I know, when you minimize then restore a window java calls repaint() on it, yet if I call repaint() myself it has a different affect.